Spring Boot Jpa is null filter not working
I have a transaction table in my PostgreSQL database. I would like to filter it by the below properties:

year
month
day

If one of them is null, then I would like to completly remove it from the query to get back all the other results.
For example:
If I provided the values like

year: 2024
month: 7
day: null
Then I would like to get back all the transactions from the provided year and month independent from the day.

As I know and found solution, this should work:
@Query("SELECT t FROM Transaction t WHERE (:year IS NULL OR t.year = :year) AND (:month IS NULL OR t.month = :month) AND (:day IS NULL OR t.day = :day) ")
List<Transaction> findTransactionByYearAndMonthAndDay(
    @Param("year") Integer year,
    @Param("month") Integer month,
    @Param("day") Integer day);

But actually it generats the below sql query:
select t1_0.id,t1_0.account_id,t1_0.amount,t1_0.category_id,t1_0.created_by_id,t1_0.day,t1_0.month,t1_0.type,t1_0.year from budget_app.transactions t1_0 where t1_0.year=? and t1_0.month=? and t1_0.day is null

You can see at the and: t1_0.day is null
But this is totally wrong, because I don't want to get back the null days, I would like to totally remove the day param from the SQL query.
So, my question is, what do I do wrong?
Thanks in advice.

Hi, which spring boot / hibernate versions are you using? I tried to replicate the issue but I correctly get the custom select statement.
